# Oracle null value sometimes fits any rule

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Does anyone know why sometimes oracle has strange behaviors towards `null` values?

For example, when I select the following query, the first row is excluded but null clearly isn't like "Test" string:

```
SELECT A.NAME FROM (
    SELECT NULL AS NAME FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'Name 1' AS NAME FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'Name 2' AS NAME FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'Name 3' AS NAME FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'Name 4' AS NAME FROM DUAL
    UNION SELECT 'Name 5' AS NAME FROM DUAL
) A WHERE UPPER(A.NAME) NOT LIKE UPPER('Test') --THIS RULE EXCLUDE DE FIRST ROW WITH NAME NULL NULL NAME
```

I'm using oracle version 11:

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE   11.2.0.4.0  Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Change to `WHERE A.NAME = NULL` - what would expect to see?  Anything compared with null is false.

Comment: @freedomn-m You could do `NULL = NULL`, it won't throw any error. Just that it won't return anything as the condition is false.

Comment: @freedomn-m Ah! I see, I didn't mean syntax error at all. My bad, I replied to your comment too quickly. I meant "semantically incorrect".

Comment: This site [has plenty of questions on Oracle and NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boracle%5D+null). Why not read some of them?

Comment: Null isn't like (or equal to) 'TEST'; but is also isn't *not* like (or equal to) 'TEST'. As APC said, this has been discussed often, including [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Nulls.html#GUID-B0BA4751-9D88-426A-84AD-BCDBD5584071),

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stated concisely, NULL is not equal to anything, including itself.

That being said, NULL comparisons with the DECODE function can be deceptive. DECODE acts as if it is using the "IS NULL" operator when comparing a NULL value rather than "=".  For example:

```
SQL> SELECT DECODE(NULL, NULL, 'Equal', 'Not Equal') result FROM dual;

RESULT
------
Equal
```

CASE statements tend to be preferred over DECODE these days for their clarity. Even so, I think that this is still worth a mention, as DECODE frequently appears in legacy code - and some folks still use it for compactness when coding simple comparisons.

Comment: Decode has strange behavior, however, the same when written using `CASE` will give just the opposite result.

Comment: `DECODE` is specifically written so that comparing NULL to NULL is treated as "equal". (Or, if you like, it's substituting "IS NULL" for "=" in the case where the comparison value in the DECODE is NULL). Basically, it intentionally violates three-value logic. CASE follows three-value logic correctly because it uses the standard comparison operators in a simple CASE expression. I don't know what it does in a searched CASE expression, but I suspect it'll treat NULL "normally", for better or worse.

Comment: True. OP initially tagged Jquery, perhaps he is unaware of the way Oracle treats NULL unlike other databases/languages. I have seen so many legacy applications where developers have used NULL as a feature thus abusing the three-value NULL logic in Oracle.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle's behavior is standard SQL behavior; it is not "strange".

Almost any comparison with `NULL` returns `NULL`, which is treated as `FALSE`.  Some exceptions are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` boolean operations under some circumstances:  `FALSE AND NULL` and `TRUE OR NULL`.

You are thinking `NULL` means missing value.  Semantically in SQL, `NULL` means *unknown* value.  If the value is unknown, then it might match `'TEST'`.  Hence, the result of the `<>` is `NULL` and the row is filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding more to @cdub's answer, you would see a strange behavior using NULL.

**DECODE** vs **CASE** behavior:

1.

```
SELECT DECODE(NULL, NULL, 'Equal', 'Not Equal') result FROM dual;

RESULT
------
Equal
```

2.

```
SELECT
    CASE NULL
        WHEN NULL THEN 'Equal'
        ELSE 'Not Equal'
    END result
FROM
    dual;

RESULT
------
Not Equal
```

So DECODE compares as `IS NULL`, however, CASE compares as `= NULL`. The latter is more clear and it will make you wonder how to write the condition for **NOT EQUAL** expression. So basically in a nutshell,

```
nothing is = NULL
nothing is <> NULL
```

Both the above conditions are **FALSE**. However, if you want to retrieve NULLs you need to use `IS NULL`. It would return NULLs when the IS NULL condition is **TRUE**.